# XSL if-clause where variable is greater than or absent, but not less than

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML-file that looks like this.
All items in the list have a dateCreated.
Items that have been used have a dateLastUsed.
Items that haven't been used doesn't have the node dateLastUsed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stripped.xsl"?>
<report>
<dateCreated>2016-05-20T12:16:11</dateCreated>
<catalog>
 <description>Older than five, never used</description>
 <call>
  <item>
   <itemID>30580004885005</itemID>
   <dateCreated>2000-02-11</dateCreated>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
 <description>Older than five, but used threee years ago</description>
 <call>
  <item>
   <dateLastUsed>2013-10-25</dateLastUsed>
   <itemID>30580005522235</itemID>
   <dateCreated>1996-06-20</dateCreated>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
 <description>Older than five, used more than five years ago</description>
 <call>
  <item>
   <dateLastUsed>2010-04-12</dateLastUsed>
   <itemID>30580004882085</itemID>
   <dateCreated>2000-02-01</dateCreated>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
 <description>Older than five, but used this year</description>
 <call>
  <item>
   <dateLastUsed>2016-05-18</dateLastUsed>
   <itemID>30580004899105</itemID>
   <dateCreated>2000-03-29</dateCreated>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
 <description>Younger than five, used less than five years ago</description>
 <call>
  <item>
   <dateLastUsed>2016-04-12</dateLastUsed>
   <itemID>30580005334920</itemID>
   <dateCreated>2015-04-25</dateCreated>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
 <description>Younger than five, never used</description>
 <call>
  <item>
   <itemID>30580005334938</itemID>
   <dateCreated>2014-04-25</dateCreated>
  </item>
 </call>
</catalog>
</report>
```

I want to filter the list, so it only contains items that are 
1) older than five years and
2a) used more than five years ago or
2b) never used at all

1 was easily solved with an if-clause
2a was also easily solved with a second if-clause - but how to solve 2b?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="fiveYears" select="1825" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <catalog>
        <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog">

                <xsl:variable name="daysSinceCreated">
                    <xsl:call-template name="date-difference">
                        <xsl:with-param name="date1" select="call/item/dateCreated" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="date2" select="//report/dateCreated" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="daysSinceUsed">
                    <xsl:call-template name="date-difference">
                        <xsl:with-param name="date1" select="call/item/dateLastUsed" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="date2" select="//report/dateCreated" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:if test="$daysSinceCreated > $fiveYears">

                    <xsl:if test="$daysSinceUsed > $fiveYears">

                        <itemline>
                            <description><xsl:value-of select="description"/></description>
                            <dateCreated><xsl:value-of select="call/item/dateCreated"/></dateCreated>
                            <daysSinceCreated><xsl:value-of select="$daysSinceCreated"/></daysSinceCreated>
                            <dateLastUsed><xsl:value-of select="call/item/dateLastUsed"/></dateLastUsed>
                            <daysSinceUsed><xsl:value-of select="$daysSinceUsed"/></daysSinceUsed>
                        </itemline>

                    </xsl:if>

                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </catalog>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="date-difference">
    <xsl:param name="date1"/>
    <xsl:param name="date2"/>
    <xsl:param name="JDN1">
        <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$date1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="JDN2">
        <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$date2" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:value-of select="$JDN2 - $JDN1"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="JDN">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:param name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:param name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:param name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:param name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is "*older than five years*" meant to be calculated against `/report/dateCreated` as the "current" date?

Comment: Yes - in normal use it will be the same as "today"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would combine your `xsl:if` statements like this...

```
<xsl:if test="($daysSinceCreated > $fiveYears and $daysSinceUsed > $fiveYears) 
  or not(string(call/item/dateLastUsed))">
    <itemline>
      <description><xsl:value-of select="description"/></description>
      <dateCreated><xsl:value-of select="call/item/dateCreated"/></dateCreated>
      <daysSinceCreated><xsl:value-of select="$daysSinceCreated"/></daysSinceCreated>
      <dateLastUsed><xsl:value-of select="call/item/dateLastUsed"/></dateLastUsed>
      <daysSinceUsed><xsl:value-of select="$daysSinceUsed"/></daysSinceUsed>
    </itemline>
</xsl:if>
```

You could also use: `or $daysSinceUsed='NaN'` instead of checking the results of `string()` since you're still trying to calculate `$daysSinceUsed` even when it hasn't been used.